# Canvas rendering issues with Chrome 39 and hardware acceleration

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I have some problems with Chrome 39 and off-screen canvas rendering. It works fine when I load a [6000x4000 JPEG image](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/transferxl-public/Monkeys-6000x4000.jpg) into an ordinary  element:

```
var img = document.getElementById('org');
img.src = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/transferxl-public/Monkeys-6000x4000.jpg";
```

The image looks like this:

[image: Normal image]

When I load it via an off-screen image and render it to a canvas it breaks down on a lot of computers when Chrome hardware acceleration is enabled:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/transferxl-public/Monkeys-6000x4000.jpg";
```

The image is distorted (see below) and drawing the image to the canvas takes almost 10 seconds (and is blocking the GUI thread):

[image: Distorted image]

When Chrome's hardware acceleration is disabled, everything works fine. Does somebody knows how to work around this issue? Can I disable Chrome's hardware acceleration from Javascript or do you know another solution?

The complete Fiddle to demonstrate this issue can be found on http://jsfiddle.net/ramondeklein/k0wtaq9m/1/.

Comment: 6000X4000 is quite a size. I'd try to use several (4?) small canvases.

Comment: It's not the size of the canvas that matters. It's the size of the original image. My JSFiddle example writes it to a canvas of only 400 pixels wide.

Comment: Remember that your nicely compressed .jpg expands into a bitmap format when rendered on canvas. The canvas pixel array contains 6000x4000x4 = 98 million elements! That's enough to choke your GPU's. The solution is simple: use reasonably sized (smaller) images.

Comment: I just tried the Chrome 42 (Canary) version and it deals with the images properly. I agree that 6000x4000 images are very large, but modern camera's are able to shoot 24MP images and users will try to upload them.

Comment: Canvas creates a pixel array that subdivides each pixel into its red, green, blue & alpha channel values. So your 24MP image expands to 24*4=98 million element canvas pixel array! Your images are just too big to expect fast performance. It even looks like the image size is affecting the accuracy of the rendering.  Perhaps give your users a smaller image to preview on the canvas and also give them a link to download the full-sized image.

Comment: I agree that 100MB is a large, but modern computers are equiped with a lot of memory and shouldn't have an issue with a single large image. It works great with Safari and Firefox and also Chrome when hardware acceleration is disabled. I agree it would be better that users wouldn't throw 24MP images at it, but if their cameras output 24MP, then they'll try to use 24MP. I don't want to upload the full image and then download a scaled down version back to the client to crop it. This would impact bandwidth and also server resources (scaling is CPU and memory expensive).

Comment: Fair enough...I'm still doubtful about success with huge image sizes, but it looks like I can't warn you off.  I do wish you good luck!